# How to get array with all file names that in folder in resource "res" folder

Tags: blackberry

I want to get array with all file Names that in folder in  resource "res" folder, Is it possible? I am working on Blackberry UIApplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only `Class.getResourceAsStream(String name)` method, so you should know what is in the resources BEFORE calling it.